# Look in separate folders then specify message details on attached file location

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that picks the most recent PDF out of a folder and send it to a specfied email address (courtesy of the user who answered my previous post).

It is working perfectly for individual folders and various email specs but I'd also like it to look into another folder and have different message specifications if a file is found in the other folder.

My code at the moment just re-runs the process and looks in the other folder (this hasn't worked due to over complication and confusing variables). I know that a lot of you will cry looking at the attempt I've made as it is really scrappy, clunky an generally poor quality - at the moment it sends all the files that are processed with the first message spec, and the last one processed again but with the second message specification.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SendFiles()
    Dim objOutLook As Object
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim fsoFile
    Dim fsoFldr
    Dim dtNew As Date, sNew As String
    Dim newOutlookInstance As Boolean

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If GetOutlook(objOutLook, newOutlookInstance) Then

    strFile = "C:\temp\" 'path to folder
    Set fsoFldr = fso.GetFolder(strFile)
    dtNew = Now() - TimeValue("00:00:30") '30 seconds ago

    For Each fsoFile In fsoFldr.Files
        If fsoFile.DateCreated > dtNew Then
            sNew = fsoFile.Path
            With objOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                .To = "email@address.com"
                .Subject = "Example"
                .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
                .Attachments.Add sNew
                .Importance = olImportanceHigh
                .Send
            End With
        End If
    Next
    If newOutlookInstance Then objOutLook.Quit '<--| quit Outlook if an already running instance of it hasn't been found
    Set objOutLook = Nothing

Else
    MsgBox "Sorry: couldn't get a valid Outlook instance running"
End If

Dim obj As Object
Dim usdFile As String
Dim aFile
Dim aFldr
Dim dNew As Date, tNew As String
Dim newInstance As Boolean

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If GetOutlook(obj, newInstance) Then

usdFile = "H:\Supply Chain - JAN17\Depannage & Kanban Requests (AB-   TG)\Unsatisfied Depannage\"
Set aFldr = fso.GetFolder(usdFile)
dNew = Now() - TimeValue("00:00:30")

For Each aFile In aFldr.Files
    If aFile.DateCreated > dNew Then
        tNew = aFile.Path
        With obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            .To = "email.address2@gmail.com"
            .Subject = "Kanban Request - LIMITED STOCK"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
            .Attachments.Add sNew
            .Importance = olImportanceHigh
            .Send
        End With
    End If
Next

If newInstance Then obj.Quit
Set obj = Nothing

 Else
    MsgBox "Sorry: couldn't get a valid Outlook instance running"
End If

End Sub





Function GetOutlook(objOutLook As Object, newOutlookInstance As Boolean) As     Boolean
Set objOutLook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If objOutLook Is Nothing Then
    Set objOutLook = New Outlook.Application
    newOutlookInstance = True
End If
GetOutlook = Not objOutLook Is Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could refactor your code and generate a *helper* `Sub` to which demand the task to search a passed folder and send emails to passed address with passed subject:

```
Sub SendFilesFromFolder(objOutLook As Object, fso As Object, fldrName As String, emailAddress As String, subject As String, dtNew As Date)
    Dim fsoFile As File

    For Each fsoFile In fso.GetFolder(fldrName).Files
        If fsoFile.DateCreated > dtNew Then
            With objOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
                .To = emailAddress
                .subject = subject
                .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
                .Attachments.Add fsoFile.Path
                .Importance = olImportanceHigh
                .Send
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

correspondingly, your "main" code would become:

```
Sub SendFiles()
    Dim objOutLook As Object
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim dtNew As Date
    Dim newOutlookInstance As Boolean


    If GetOutlook(objOutLook, newOutlookInstance) Then
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        dtNew = Now() - TimeValue("00:00:30") '30 seconds ago

        SendFilesFromFolder objOutLook, _
                            fso, _
                            "C:\temp\", _
                            "email@address.com", _
                            "Example", _
                            dtNew

        SendFilesFromFolder objOutLook, _
                            fso, _
                            "H:\Supply Chain - JAN17\Depannage & Kanban Requests (AB-   TG)\Unsatisfied Depannage\", _
                            "email.address2@gmail.com", _
                            "Kanban Request - LIMITED STOCK", _
                            dtNew

        If newOutlookInstance Then objOutLook.Quit '<--| quit Outlook if an already running instance of it hasn't been found
        Set objOutLook = Nothing
        Set fso = Nothing

    Else
        MsgBox "Sorry: couldn't get a valid Outlook instance running"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it is coming up with an error in the helper sub - the GetFolder().Files errors and says that "object doesn't support this property or method". @user3598756

Comment: just swapped `objOutLook As Object` and `fso As Object` between `SendFilesFromFolder()` parameter list and argument list call: see edited code